# #light-синтаксис.

Tags: f#

В книге "Программироване на F#" Сошникова Д.В. есть пример

```
let solve (a,b,c) =
   let D = b*b-4.*a*c in
    ((-b+sqrt(D))/(2.*a),(-b-sqrt(D))/(2.*a))
 in solve (1.0,2.0,-3.0);;
```

В результате выполнения получаем: **val it : float * float = (1.0, -3.0)**
Далее в книге модифицируется пример так (применение #light-синтаксиса):

```
let solve (a,b,c) =
   let D = b*b-4.*a*c 
   ((-b+sqrt(D))/(2.*a),(-b-sqrt(D))/(2.*a));
solve (1.0,2.0,-3.0);;
```

Но результат почему то уже не такой, а именно получается: **val solve : float * float * float -> float * float**
В чем ошибка?
Вот скриншот листинга, идущего вместе с книгой:
[image]

Нужна ли точка с запятой в конце 3 строки во втором листинге?

Comment: `solve`-то и правда ` float * float * float -> float * float`, а вот `solve (1.0,2.0,-3.0)` должен быть просто `float * float`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У меня всё работает (VS 2012):

```
Microsoft (R) F# Interactive version 11.0.60315.1
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All Rights Reserved.

For help type #help;;

> let solve (a,b,c) =
    let D = b*b-4.*a*c in
      ((-b+sqrt(D))/(2.*a),(-b-sqrt(D))/(2.*a)) in
solve (1.0,2.0,-3.0);;

val solve : a:float * b:float * c:float -> float * float
val it : float * float = (1.0, -3.0)

> let solve (a,b,c) =
    let D = b*b-4.*a*c
      ((-b+sqrt(D))/(2.*a),(-b-sqrt(D))/(2.*a))
solve (1.0,2.0,-3.0);;

val solve : a:float * b:float * c:float -> float * float
val it : float * float = (1.0, -3.0)
```

Comment: <pre>`((-b+sqrt(D))/(2.*a),(-b-sqrt(D))/(2.*a))` </pre>  

в этой строке у вас нет запятой, так и должно быть?
в VS 2010 у меня что то никак не заработало.

Comment: Решил проблему, надо было добавить пробел вначале первой строчки " let solve (a,b,c) =". Теперь числовой результат выводится!
Вопрос с точкой с запятой в конце 3 строки актуален, нужна ли там точка с запятой?

Comment: Я пробовал в interactive window VS 2012.

---
В неинтерактивном режиме `;;` не должно быть нужно. (В режиме `#light "off"` двойная точка с запятой используется как знак окончания декларации верхнего уровня для совместимости с OCaml.)